# Type Mismatch when adding registry key

Tags: vbscript, registry

I have a script that creates a signature and puts it in the Microsoft signature folder. it has all three versions and they are called Hemmera.htm, Hemmera.rtf and Hemmera.txt. I can manually load them and everything is fine.

However I then have this section in my code:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\MailSettings\NewSignature" , "Hemmera", "REG_SZ"
if err <> 0 then
    errMsg = errMsg & vbcrlf & "Error Creating New Signature Registry Key - " & err.number & " - " & err.description
end if
```

to set the signature automatically but it always gives me the error:

```
Error Creating New Signature Registry Key - 13 - Type mismatch
```

I have tried with and without the , "REG_SZ" bit at the end as some examples I have seen show it, others dont!

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Your code works here. You are aware your code creates a value not a key because there is no trailing backspace. Whichever, both work.

Possibly it's the notepad issue.

If using notepad to write it copy and paste into wordpad to check line breaks. Notepad totally ignores and hides carriage returns but other programs don't. Notepad only looks for line feeds. If coping from browser based documentation such as web pages and help systems sometimes stray carriage returns get invisibly inserted in notepad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Serenity. I didn't realise I was creating a value and not a key. However adding the trailing backslash (I guess you meant backslash not backspace) hasn't made a difference (as you guessed it wouldn't). 

I'm using Notepad++ as my editor and I have removed and re-added all the newlines in my code but this hasn't made a difference either.

Comment: I heard that notepad++ has same issue as notepad. The root of notepad's issue is it uses an multiline edit control. Both Edit controls and command prompt use LF. Rich Edit Controls (as in Wordpad) and VBScript, web browsers, office, etc use CR. Paste into Wordpad to check.

Comment: In Notepad++ you can choose your EOL format. Mine is set to Windows (Not Unix or old Mac formats). However I have tried copying and pasting into wordpad but to no avail.

Comment: So you mean my code works!
I guarantee to you that it doesn't and gives the type mismatch error!!